# quick method to save ruby objects on command line?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, command-line

I'm using Netbeans to develop my RoR project so it is managing the SQL database. How can I make quick changes (i.e. edit row-by-row) to my DB, preferably in command line?

i'm thinking - changing temporary passwords and users for testing purposes. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ruby script/console` in your rails application directory. From there, you can do things like:

```
u = User.find(:first)
u.password = 'something_else'
u.save
```

or

```
users = User.find(:all)
users.each { |u| u.password = 'something'; u.save }
```

which will update all users' passwords.

Comment: You can also create new objects a la User.create(:name => "Foo", :active => true).

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

- run `script/console` and manipulate your Rails' model objects directly from the command line
- run `script/dbconsole` which will drop you into the command line for your RDBMS (assuming that your `database.yml` file is configured to access your database correctly). Then use SQL to do what you need to do

([Railscast on Console Tricks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/48-console-tricks))

Comment: i've used script/console to query the DB in the past, but have have have encountered "undefined method" exception when attempting to save objects. Is this probably a syntactical error or something more fundamental?  This is what I have been trying:

prompt> Object.save("name" => "john", "password" => "foo"... ETC)

Comment: You want Object.create("name" => "john", "password" => "foo")

Comment: You should be doing o = Object.create(:name => "john", :password => "foo"), followed by o.save

Comment: The save method optionally accepts only one parameter, which is a boolean that indicates whether validation should be performed or not.

Comment: @John Topley - Object.create automatically calls Object.save, Object.new doesn't ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the direct mysql interface, but I'd use script/console to go through your model classes unless you really need direct DB access.